# Observable LINQ inconsistent exceptions thrown

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive, observable

In my quest to write a stock market trader [`IObserver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449(v=vs.110).aspx) I've encountered three errors mostly thrown from within the `Reactive Extensions` library.

I have the following `CompanyInfo` class:

```
public class CompanyInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

And an `IObservable<CompanyInfo>` called `StockMarket`:

```
public class StockMarket : IObservable<CompanyInfo>
```

My `Observer` looks like the following:

```
public class StockTrader : IObserver<CompanyInfo>
{
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Market Closed");
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }

    public void OnNext(CompanyInfo value)
    {
        WriteStock(value);
    }

    private void WriteStock(CompanyInfo value) { ... }
}
```

I run the following code:

```
StockMarket market = GetStockMarket();
StockTrader trader = new StockTrader();

IObservable<CompanyInfo> differential = market  //[F, 1], [S, 5], [S, 4], [F, 2]
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)                       //[F, 1], [F, 2]; [S, 5], [S, 4]
    .SelectMany(x => x                  //4, 8, 2, 3
        .Buffer(2, 1)                   //(4, 8), (8, 2), (2, 3), (3)
        .SkipLast(1)                    //(4, 8), (8, 2), (2, 3)
        .Select(y => new CompanyInfo    //(+100%), (-75%), (+50%)
        {
            Name = x.Key,
            Value = (y[1].Value - y[0].Value) / y[0].Value
        })                                      //[F, +100%]; [S, -20%]
    );

using (IDisposable subscription = differential.Subscribe(trader))
{
    Observable.Wait(market);
}
```

One of three errors occur:

- The following `ArgumentException` is thrown ***from within the `Reactive Extensions`***:

  > System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
  >      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
  >      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
  >      at System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.GroupBy'3._.OnNext(TSource value)
- The following `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

  > Parameter name: index
  >      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
  >      at System.Collections.Generic.List'1.get_Item(Int32 index)
  >      at StockMarketTests.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__2(IList'1 y)
  >      at System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Select'2._.OnNext(TSource value)
- The text of the `Console` tweaks sporadically (The color should be consistance):

[image: Console]

What could cause those bizzare symptoms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the greatest things about the concept of `Reactive Extensions` is the ability to subscribe to an *'occurrence'* ([`IObservable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx)) which happened *'somewhere'* and applying object oriented concepts on this *'occurrence'* - this without having to know where that *'somewhere'* is.

***This way `Reactive Extensions` simplifies the `event` oriented programming and [`producer-consumer` problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) a lot***.

> [image: Great Power]

The ability to subscribe to an [`IObservable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) without knowing the source of the observed data forces the subscriber to assume ***notifications are unpredictable***. In other words, when observing an [`IObservable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) ***you should assume notifications can be delivered concurrently***.

<sub>Due to a behavioural contract of `Reactive Externsions`, `IObservables` should produce one item at a time. Usually, that's what happen, but sometimes external implementations don't follow that contract.</sub>

*Lets take a look on each of the three problems:*

### *[`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229301(v=vs.103).aspx) is not thread-safe*

---

[`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229301(v=vs.103).aspx) works by returning an `IObservable<IGroupedObservable<T>>`, its `OnNext` method calls the outer `IObservable`'s `OnNext` with the `IGroupedObservable<T>` which matches the current notification. it does so by keeping one `IGroupedObservable<T>` <sub>(more accurately one `Subject<T>`)</sub> for each key inside a `Dictionary` - which is unsurprisingly - ***not a `ConcurrentDictionary`***. That means ***two proximate notifications can cause a double insert***.

### *[`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244306(v=vs.103).aspx) is not alone*

---

[`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244306(v=vs.103).aspx)'s thread-safety is determined by its provided delegate. In the case above, the delegate provided to the [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244306(v=vs.103).aspx) method relies on the fact that `Buffer(2, 1)` will provide a list with the size of 2. ***`Buffer` contains a `Queue`, which is not concurrent***, therefore ***when iterated from multiple threads - `Buffer`'s `Queue` can provide us some unexpected results***.

another `Exception` which could be thrown from the same reason is [`NullReferenceException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx) if `y` would be provided `null`, or an [`InvalidOperationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `Queue` could be modified while it's being iterated.

### *Even the basic observation is not safe*

---

Last but not least, even when you do only the basic observation, the `StockTrader`'s `OnNext` method is modifying the console in a non-[atomic operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) which causes the wierd text layout.

### *So what can you do?*

---

[image: Threads]

The [`Synchronize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229583(v=vs.103).aspx) method exists to make you able to validate that you are subscribing to a *linear* [`IObservable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) which means ***no more than one invocation on `OnNext` method can occur concurrently***.

Since even the [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229301(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method is not thread-safe, the [`Synchronize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229583(v=vs.103).aspx) method needs to be invoked in the beginning of the chain:

```
IObservable<CompanyInfo> differential = market  //[F, 1], [S, 5], [S, 4], [F, 2]
    .Synchronize()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)                       //[F, 1], [F, 2]; [S, 5], [S, 4]
    .SelectMany(x => x                  //4, 8, 2, 3
        .Buffer(2, 1)                   //(4, 8), (8, 2), (2, 3), (3)
        .SkipLast(1)                    //(4, 8), (8, 2), (2, 3)
        .Select(y => new CompanyInfo    //(+100%), (-75%), (+50%)
        {
            Name = x.Key,
            Value = (y[1].Value - y[0].Value) / y[0].Value
        })                                      
    );                                          //[F, +100%]; [S, -20%]
```

Note that `Synchronize` adds another proxy `Observable` to your query, hence it will make the query a little bit slower, therefore ***you should avoid using it when it is not required***.

Comment: It's like you've turned SO into your own personal blog post.

Comment: Haha, helped someone who encountered this problem, thought about sharing the solution here...

Comment: -1 I do not agree with this advice. @Enigmativity is on the money. This long post obscures the heart of the matter. The `IObservable<T>` contract is not completely enforceable by .NET. It includes the requirement that `OnXXX` calls are serialized. End Of. If you get calls that aren't serialized, it's a bug in the observable. Now either you own or trust the observable or you don't and then you code appropriately. Assuming that all observables are bug-ridden is not good advice - the end game there is putting Synchronize after every observable. Code bloat and performance dips follow.

Comment: ... you need to be pragmatic and aware of the possibility, and make appropriate decisions. None of this feels like a newsflash to me. The implementers of Rx made *deliberate* decisions NOT to enforce or check serializing precisely because of the performance implications. There is a real danger that this advice might drive someone down the wrong path and lead them to write a bunch of unnecessarily over-cautious code. Hopefully these comments provide some balance.

Comment: I don't understand what serialization has to do with this post but anyway: I clearly ***DO NOT SUGGEST*** using `.Synchronize()` on every `Observable<T>` but what you encounter this kind of bugs you have to be aware that there are some things that happen in the background that might not be under your control, and that's a way to fix that ***if you have to***.

Comment: @TamirVered - James' use of the word "serialized" is correct - he means "one comes after the other" - serialized - and not the sense of serializing and deserializing objects (which effectively means all the parts of the object are laid out one after another anyway).

Comment: This answer is very misleading as to the suitability of Rx to do its job. The operators of Rx are as solid a bit of code as I've ever seen. They are very robust and are built solidly against the Rx contract. It's only when a source observable doesn't follow the contract that things go wrong. The problem with the code is the implementation of `StockMarket`. If it were written to follow the contract it would all work fine. That should have been the point.

Comment: You cant force the developers of every external assembly you are using to fix their code to follow that contract. you ***can*** on the other hand be aware of when it's their bug and use this workaround. The last note makes it clear that you shouldn't use it on every observable you are observing.

Comment: Equally, you shouldn't blindly work around a possible problem in an external assembly. If it's happening, frankly you shouldn't be using that component *at all* - because it's horribly broken. You say that `Synchronize` allows you to validate correctness - it doesn't do that at all. It doesn't flag incorrect Observables (which validation would do), it merely hides the problem. IMHO, `Synchronize` is best used deliberately as part of the transition to an `IObservable<T>` to serialize a source of concurrent events from a non-Rx source - *not* to fix a broken observable.

Comment: It fixes them when they are broken in the terms of working concurrently instead of not working concurrently, not in the terms of not functional...

Comment: For example, the `Observable` in the example works by invoking events from few `Threads` started in the `GetStockMarket` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is not with the query, nor with Rx per se. The problem is likely coming from either of your actual `StockMarket` or `StockTrader` implementations.

Now, it's likely that the issue is being caused because you are creating two subscriptions to your `market` observable.

When you write this:

```
using (IDisposable subscription = differential.Subscribe(trader))
{
    Observable.Wait(market);
}
```

...you are getting two subscriptions to `market`. One in `differential.Subscribe(trader)` and the other because of `Observable.Wait(market);`.

I suspect that two concurrent subscriptions are causing your issues, but without seeing the implementation of `StockMarket` we can't tell why it's throwing.

This is the danger of implementing your own observable and observer implementations. You should avoid doing that. It would be better to have a property `IObservable<CompanyInfo> CompanyValues { get; }` hanging off of `CompanyInfo` that is built using the standard Rx operators.

And you should always avoid blocking operations like `.Wait(...)`.

As a quick test I would replace your current `Observable.Wait(market);` with a `Thread.Sleep(?)` with a sufficiently long sleep period to see if your code behaves. Of course you'll need to make sure that you are producing values on a background scheduler (like `Scheduler.Default`).

I ran this code to test your query:

```
public class CompanyInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class StockTrader : IObserver<CompanyInfo>
{
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Market Closed");
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }

    public void OnNext(CompanyInfo value)
    {
        WriteStock(value);
    }

    private void WriteStock(CompanyInfo value) { Console.WriteLine($"{value.Name} = {value.Value}"); }
}

public class StockMarket : IObservable<CompanyInfo>
{
    private CompanyInfo[] _values = new CompanyInfo[]
    {
        new CompanyInfo() { Name = "F", Value = 1 },
        new CompanyInfo() { Name = "S", Value = 5 },
        new CompanyInfo() { Name = "S", Value = 4 },
        new CompanyInfo() { Name = "F", Value = 2 },
    };

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<CompanyInfo> observable)
    {
        return _values.ToObservable().ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default).Subscribe(observable);
    }
}
```

...with this:

```
StockMarket market = new StockMarket();
StockTrader trader = new StockTrader();

IObservable<CompanyInfo> differential = market  //[F, 1], [S, 5], [S, 4], [F, 2]
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)                       //[F, 1], [F, 2]; [S, 5], [S, 4]
    .SelectMany(x => x                  //4, 8, 2, 3
        .Buffer(2, 1)                   //(4, 8), (8, 2), (2, 3), (3)
        .SkipLast(1)                    //(4, 8), (8, 2), (2, 3)
        .Select(y => new CompanyInfo    //(+100%), (-75%), (+50%)
        {
            Name = x.Key,
            Value = (y[1].Value - y[0].Value) / y[0].Value
        })                                      //[F, +100%]; [S, -20%]
    );

IDisposable subscription = differential.Subscribe(trader);

Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Not once did I get it to crash or cause any exceptions.

Comment: I will tomorrow give you both implementations with explaination why this is wrong, the problem is concurrency and concurrency alone. your implementation is not triggered from multiple threads, therefore you are not having the same issues. also, its a matter of timing and one can get different results if the timing is not right.

Comment: Also, it happens with one subscription too.

Comment: @TamirVered - Rx has a behavioural contract to produce one value at a time. If the source data doesn't obey the contract then a `.Synchronize()` may be necessary, but I have shown that the issue isn't with the query, but the source.

Comment: You didnt show that. your implementation is a stateless `cold Observable`, of couse it will have no thread issues, also you do not push notifications from multiple threads. If i push notifications to my `StockMarket` from one thread only I am having no problem. I will share my `GetStockMarket` method later so you can see what I saying.

Comment: @TamirVered - You only have threading issues if the source observable doesn't behave according to the contract. It doesn't matter if it is cold or not. I don't know what you mean by stateless though. You should be able to push multiple values from multiple threads without a problem if your source behaves itself. If it doesn't, then as per your answer, pop in a `.Synchronize()` and you're good.

Comment: The point is that you don't always have control on the code of the `Observable` you are ovserving, and you have to not be surprised when this kind of things have.

Comment: @Enigmativity +1. See my comments elsewhere.

Comment: @JamesWorld - Thanks, James. This question has ended up being rather damaging I think.